Node,js code not printing 24 bits colors in Git Bash terminal, But direct commands works
I'm experiencing a weird problem with printing 24-bit colors in the Git Bash terminal using Node.js. When I run a simple JavaScript script that uses ANSI codes to print 24-bit (true color), only the basic 16 colors are displayed. However, when I run a equivalent code directly into the same terminal, the 24-bit colors display perfectly (showing that the Bash terminal supports the 24-biy colors). The colors also are shown correctly when I run the code through a starting script linked to the windows PATH.
My node version is v20.10.0, my git version is 2.47.0.windows.2, my OS is Windows and the terminal emulator is xterm-256color
After quite the amount of tests, research and some suggestions (I was confusing terminal emulator with the terminal), I narrowed where the problem could be. This is the start script that is linked to windows PATH:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'term:' $TERM
echo 'term_program:' $TERM_PROGRAM
for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  process.stdout.write(`\x1b[38;2;${i};0;0m█\x1b[0m`);
}
node test.js

the test.js file has equivalent prints in it. When I run the script from the path, it prints everything correctly.
But, when I try to execute the script or JavaScript file directly from the folder, the JavaScript side loses the terminal parameter and displays the colors incorrectly.
Why this happens, even though both ways use the same script file? And how can I run the code without using the windows PATH?

Terminal emulator software is not required to support any particular set of legacy screen/cursor control codes and escape sequences.

@Pointy Sorry, I am confused at your answer. Could you explain more about it? Why does the node code doesn't print the colors at the terminal?

Is the terminal emulator related to Node? I know some terminals don't display the colors, but the one I am using does, except when receiving from the code I wrote.
$ node test.js this doesn't display the color. In the code is only a print function.
$ echo -e "\x1b[38;2;255;0;0m█\x1b[38;2;200;0;0m█\x1b[0m\n" this does display the color. Both commands are executed on the same terminal.

A terminal emulator is a piece of software that provides the familiar experience (well, not so familiar now in 2024) of using a simple text-only terminal device. Back in the 1970s and 1980s, there were dozens, hundreds of manufacturers of terminals, and there was very little compatibility in the control code commands that they understood. The "escape" character codes, probably the closest thing to a standard, were only used in a minority of devices (though possibly a better share of the market if you consider units in use).
